# Defining individual glyphs breaks kerning

Tags: fonts, macros, kerning

When I create shortcuts for individual glyphs, no kerning is applied.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\myF}{\textit{f}}
\newcommand{\myA}{\textit{a}}
\begin{document}
\myF\myA\par \textit{fa}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Any way to retain kerning without having to type things like `\textit{fa}` directly?

Anticipating some questions about why I do this:

Just to make it clear, I define such shortcuts for more sensisble cases than the one above, such as (1) when the glyphs aren't characters you can find on a keyboard, and I want to avoid typing things like `\char"XXXX` every time, codes I would have to look up all the time, and (2) when using a transcription system in which upright and italic glyphs mean different things - in which case I predefine each glyph (many of which aren't even in Unicode) so that I don't need to remember whether that specific glyph in that context is supposed to be italic or upright.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\myF}{\textit{f}}
\newcommand{\myA}{\textit{a}}
\newcommand{\yourF}{\begingroup\itshape f\endgroup}
\newcommand{\yourA}{\begingroup\itshape a\endgroup}
\begin{document}

\myF\myA

\yourF\yourA

\textit{fa}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I get the same with `{\itshape f}`, so why the `{\begingroup .. \endgroup}`?

Comment: @Sverre: Remove them and then try out `\yourF abc clclclc`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I did - I see no difference ... ??

Comment: You should. Without the grouping the following text should be in italic too.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Oh! But that happens with `\begingroup ... \endgroup` as well!

Comment: @Sverre: Not in Davids example. When I type abc behind `\yourA` it is upright.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer No sorry, it just seemed to be the case because the preceding line the document tested the effect of `\itshape` only. EDIT: That is, you're right.